# Using one Java source file in two different projects, both under development

Tags: java, spring, architecture, client-server, code-sharing

I am developing a Spring (Java framework for server-side web-development)web application, which will respond to another client-side Java application(which uses socket communication) by a JSON object. At the same time, I'm working on both server-side and client-side Java applications.

The problem is that I have a bunch of files(say, a Json variable interfaces) that are being used at both projects. For now, I have duplicate copies of that interface, in different packages in the two projects. But this causes inconsistency, because I have to update the both files whenever I need to make a change in the interface.

Does anyone have a neat solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should treat your shared code at the package level and not the file level.

You should create a package of interface definitions that are used by both the client and server side of your architecture and whenever that package changes, both sides will have to change accordingly.

**EDIT:**

I wasn't explicit about it but zellus' suggestion about importing the common code as a jar is a good one.

Comment: this might be a silly question:
Should I create this package in on of these projects src directory? Then what happens if I move the server-side and client-side codes to different machines?

Comment: However you manage your source code the paths should all be relative instead of absolute and so it shouldn't matter if you change machines.

Comment: Well, you're right about using relative path. what I meant was that since these two project are supposed to run in different machines, what happens to the shared package when I move each project to their own machine? Then I have to copy the package to both server and client machines, right?(Assume that I want to still be able to edit the source when I move the projects to different machines)

Comment: @green-i - Keep the source code on one machine (e.g. your development box), and copy the compiled code (e.g. JAR files) to the machines you need to run it on.  You shouldn't need to edit the source code on two or more machines.

Answer (score 2):

You might create a separate project for your common JSON code. Using subversion, svn:externals allow a neat integration on the source level. Importing the common code as jar file is another approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using maven, you could create a local maven project containing all the classes you might need in different projects and add this dependency to your pom.xml which requires these classes.